# Ionic Refused to display 'https://withpersona.com/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'deny'

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, ionic-framework, web

recently I have been implementing my Ionic App with Persona KYC. But I still have a problem with the integration. When I execute the javascript code in Ionic I get the error mentioned in the title. If someone can help me and the community to resolve this would be awesome.

Script:

```
function openClient(uid) {
const client = new Persona.Client({
    templateId: 'itmpl_KxEjwiJXJMntb25dJXdrBnTP',
    environmentId: 'env_gQDYrnzBZfXSiPWWdj4VSRGo',
    referenceId: uid,
    onReady: () => client.open(),
    onComplete: ({ inquiryId, status, fields }) => {
        console.log(`Completed inquiry ${inquiryId} with status ${status}`);
    }
 });
}
function cancelClient() { client.cancel(true); }
```

Typescript method calling the javascript function:

```
declare var openClient; 
async openVerifyIdentityModal() {
  if (!this.verifyIdentity) {
    await openClient(this.auth.currentUser.uid);
    await Preferences.set({ key: "verifyidentity", value: "true" });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Ed here from Persona. Thanks for sharing this - I asked our dev team to shed some light. Here's their suggestion:

**Error: ReferenceError: self is not defined when using next.js**

***Error: Refused to display 'https://withpersona.com/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'deny'***

ReferenceError: self is not defined when using next.js
The Persona JS SDK does not support server rendering. Add the following snippet:

```
    TypeScript

import dynamic from "next/dynamic";

export const PersonaInquiry = dynamic(
  () => import('persona').then((module) => module.Inquiry),
  {ssr: false}
);
```

Refused to display 'https://withpersona.com/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'deny'

**What this means**
This error message is a result of a security feature that Persona offers when you integrate Persona using Embedded Flow.

Persona lets you specify, via an allowlist, which domains can load the embedded flow. You should specify only the domains where you embed your Persona flow. Potential attackers will then be blocked from embedding and loading your flow on their domain.

If you see this error, it means that the domain the embedded flow in being loaded on is not on the allowlist.

**How to fix**
If you see this error, go to the Embedded Flow integration page in the Persona Dashboard, and locate "Step 3 Configure allowed domains". Here, you'll see the Domain allowlist.

Ensure that:

1. The domain from which you are trying to load the Embedded Flow (and where you're seeing the error message) is on the Domain allowlist.
2. The domain in the Domain allowlist is correctly spelled and properly formatted. Note: a domain name should NOT include the http:// or https:// part of the URL.

If you are testing, please note:

- If you want to load an embedded flow on localhost, you must use an embedded flow that points to your Sandbox environment. An embedded flow that points to your Production environment cannot be loaded on localhost.
  If you have a more complex setup, please note:
- If your embedded flow is loaded on a webpage that is itself loaded as an iframe on another parent webpage, you must specify all parent origins by setting the frameAncestors option in the JS SDK. See Parameters for details.

We also updated our support documentation to provide you with insights as to where to find a solution for this error message:

https://docs.withpersona.com/docs/troubleshooting-common-errors

Please reach out to our team on support@withpersona.com in case the suggested fix doesn't resolve the error.

Thanks,
Ed

Comment: While it's nice to have company's reach out on stackoverflow, link only answers are generally not acceptable as links can change and break with time. Can you please revise your answer to include the fix specific to the poster's issue? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Common error messages are listed below.

To learn how to fix each error, visit Troubleshooting common errors with Embedded Flow in Persona's technical documentation. As always, feel free to reach out to support@withpersona.com if you have further questions.

Error: ReferenceError: self is not defined when using next.js
Error: Refused to display 'https://withpersona.com/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'deny'

Comment: Hi Guys, did you find a way to use it on Ionic? I am struggling with this. Thanks